# how to add a command item row for each grid row in telerik rad grid?

Tags: grid, telerik, telerik-grid

I have a usual rad grid. I was wondering if I could have a list of action buttons in a row rather than in columns. the buttons will vary based on each rows.
any ideas?

here is what i've experimented so far.. but no success for the nested view..

```
    <telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    AllowSorting="True" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="5" GridLines="None" ShowGroupPanel="True">
    <MasterTableView DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataKeyNames="id" AllowMultiColumnSorting="True"
        GroupLoadMode="Server">
        <Columns>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="ref" HeaderText="Ref" SortExpression="ContactName"
                UniqueName="ContactName">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="title" HeaderText="Title" SortExpression="ContactTitle"
                UniqueName="ContactTitle">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>

        </Columns>
        <NestedViewSettings DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2">
            <ParentTableRelation>
                <telerik:GridRelationFields DetailKeyField="vacancyid" MasterKeyField="id" />
            </ParentTableRelation>
        </NestedViewSettings>
        <NestedViewTemplate>
            <asp:Panel ID="NestedViewPanel" runat="server" CssClass="viewWrap">
                <div class="contactWrap">
                    <fieldset style="padding: 10px;">
                        <legend style="padding: 5px;"><b>Detail info for Customer:&nbsp; &nbsp;</b>
                        </legend>
                        <table>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <table>
                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>
                                                        location:
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <asp:Label ID="cityLabel" Text='<%#Bind("locationid") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>

                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>

                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
            </asp:Panel>
        </NestedViewTemplate>
    </MasterTableView>
    <PagerStyle Mode="NumericPages"></PagerStyle>
    <ClientSettings AllowDragToGroup="true" />
</telerik:RadGrid>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2"
    SelectCommand="select vacancyid, locationid from vacancylocationlocation where vacancyid = @id" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NorthwindConnectionString %>"
    runat="server">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="id" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" 
    SelectCommand="select id, ref, title from vacancy where id = 1045" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NorthwindConnectionString %>"
    runat="server"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: I'm confused, you said action buttons, but I don't see any buttons embedded in the template...

Comment: yes its just an experiment. buttons will depend on master table primary key. is there any way to do it programatically ? current problem I'm having is I cant get the nestedtemplate query to work.. dont know why.. if i could make it work then I could try to add buttons in there.

Comment: For dynamic buttons, you can use an inner repeater and bind the list of buttons when you bind the grid.  You could also include the list of buttons and show/hide the buttons you want.  To Bind the buttons depends on the HierarchyLoadMode - you can set to ServerOnDemand, to load when the expander fires, or set it to load immediately.  When needing data, it fires the GridDetailViewDataBind event, which you can listen to and bind appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by in a row?  Do you mean all in one cell?  You can do that by using a GridTemplateColumn.  If you want buttons to appear as a nested item, meaning you have to hit the drop down icon on the left to see more info, you can put whatever content you want there by adding a NestedViewTemplate (or similarly named).

HTH.